# Wait and stop executing code till an event handler fires

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have code that launches a series of functions that I may not change:

```
doFirstThing();
doSecondThing();
doThirdThing();
// more functions...
```

Every function creates an event handler. What I want the function to do is wait till the event handler fires and only then return and let the next function execute. I can't make the first function's event listener execute `doSecondThing()` by itself (the second executing the third one and so on), because the order and amount of functions that will be executed is different every time.

The only solution that I could think of has the event listener change a boolean like `eventFired` to true, while there is an infinite while loop in the function checking and waiting for the boolean to become true.

For example, let's say there is a function `newText(str)` that changes the text of a button and then waits for the button to be clicked. Once that is done, the function finally returns. The code that executes this function an unknown amount of times with unknown values is automatically generated and is different every time, so for example:

```
newText('Fizz');
newText('Buzz');
// some random code
newText('Foo');
// more code
newText('Bar');
```

So the expected behavior is to have a button with the text "Fizz". Once it is clicked, the text changes to "Buzz" and so on till "Bar" is clicked. There might be some other code between the four function calls, so I don't think it's possible to just make the first function create an event handler which when fired calls the next one and so on.

I believe that would become resource intensive, and I could use `setTimeout()` to check it just a few times per second, but I feel like there is a better, cleaner and more effective way to do it that I can't find. Or is this the only and best way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Why not have the next function do it's thing in the event listener for the previous item?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? Let's say that every function changes the text of a button to something new. Then it waits for the button to be clicked. Once it is clicked, the next function is executed that changes the text again and waits, and so on. The thing is that the function that the event listener executes can't be the one that changes the text.

Comment: Can you change the functions at all?  Like sending a callback function to them?

Comment: The order and amount of functions is always different, and they all do slightly different things. I can't place the code of the next function in the event handler instead. I also added an example to perhaps make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you're asking. Maybe if you post the actual code you have would make things more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *await* the button to be clicked. For that you need to convert the click event into a *promise* that resolves when a user clicked the button:

```
const once = (selector, event) => new Promise( 
    res => document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(event, res));

const setText = (selector, text) => { 
    document.querySelector(selector).textContent = text
};
```

Now its quite easy to do what you want:

```
(async function(){
  setText("#btn", "click me");
  await once("#btn", "click");
  setText("#btn", "again please");
  await once("#btn", "click");
  setText("#btn", "done!");
})();
```

Comment: Where does it say OP is using ES6?

Comment: @noobishPro where does it say something else?? And by the way http://babeljs.com, and this is ES7...

Comment: ES7, my bad. Still, this is NOT the standard and still not natively supported by any (?) browser. It requires third party stuff which is why it's a thing of its own. A newbie trying to learn stuff might get confused as to why your answer "Isn't working". The syntax may not make sense to someone who doesn't work with ES7 yet. If I post a question about PHP, do you assume I use the ZEND framework as well?

Comment: @IrkenInvader does it automatically work on any website? Yes? Cool. No? 3rd party. It will require some type of interpreter. This makes it a solution which only helps specific people in specific scenarios. As I've said, it's made clear absolutely nowhere that OP is using any of it, nor should it be assumed.

Comment: @noobishPro this is blantly wrong. ES7 is supported by all major browsers with more or less recent versions (~ 1 Year). Everyone that is seriously doing web development should have such kind of browser. And anyone writing for production should transfer the code to ES3 ( and no, you dont wanna actually write code with that)

Comment: Whelp, guess I've just learnt something new... Strange thing is I tried stuff like this a while ago (in chrome) and I got a hella lot of errors on the new functions like `await`, `async` and `=>`. My mind must be playing games :') Sorry for the bother

Comment: Hello, so I did try your solution and it did work. I had to move all my code inside the async function, but here's an issue. I want the setText() and await part to be inside a function, not as a part of code. But I can't use await in a function that isn't async. And if I set the function async, then JavaScript won't wait for that function to finish it's work and will just continue executing.

Comment: @thomas tom the function needs to be async. Thats how it is. Its difficult for me to help you in your case as i dont see your code, feel free to ask another question...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to dispatch custom events. You can control the order of operation by firing a custom event that would execute code specific to that event. In the follow example, there are "Option" events created. Given your scenario, when a click of the button occurs, logic can be used to determine what to do next (which option to take). Once that is decided, simply dispatch the custom event. Nothing occurs without the next event firing.

Essentially, the operation is bound to a custom event. The order the event is dispatched dictates the order the code is executed.

Example code below (can't demo because the on-line tools don't support custom events):

```
//Starting button
var buttonLabel = 'Fizz';
var currentOption = '';
// options represent the various "next steps" to take
var options = ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5',];
var events = [];
options.forEach(o=>{
   var event = document.createEvent(o);
   events.push(event);
});
console.log(events);

function newText(){
  document.querySelector('button').textContent = buttonLabel;
}

function buttonClick(){
  switch (buttonLabel){
    case 'Fizz' :
      buttonLabel = 'Buzz';
      break;
    case 'Buzz' :
      buttonLabel = 'Foo';
      break;
    case 'Foo' :
      buttonLabel = 'Bar';
      break;
    case 'Bar' :
      buttonLabel = 'FooBar';
      break;
    case 'FooBar' :
      buttonLabel = 'Fizz';
      break;
    default :
      buttonLabel = 'What?';
      break;
  }
  currentOption = options[Math.random(0, options.length)];
  document.dispatchEvent(Math.random(0, options.length));
}
// Capture the button click...
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
// This sets up the activities (randomized here but just for demo)
document.addEventListener('option1', ()=>{
   alert('Option 1: \n running newText()...')

   newText();
});
document.addEventListener('option2', ()=>{
   alert('Option 2: \n doing something else...')
});

document.addEventListener('option3', ()=>{
   alert('Option 3: \n running newText()...')
   newText();
});

document.addEventListener('option4', ()=>{
   alert('Option 4: \n doing something else...')
});

document.addEventListener('option5', ()=>{
   alert('Option 5: \n running newText()...')
   newText();
});
```